# Scrolling does not work when browser size is reduced and header is fixed while using bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am fixing header using the following code given below and the header gets fixed also but when i reduce the size of browser window the scrolling of the browser windows stops working and i cannot see the whole content. Please give any suggestions.

```
 div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i personally don't think there is anyway to fix one way or another. the best way is to reduce your content is it can fix in a 320px wide screen.

Comment: i think there is some other problem in the way i am fixing the header because i scroll but the contents does not appear.

Comment: most people's problem with fixed nav bars are when you scroll down, content appears in multiple rows and etc, else the content stretches across and out of the screen. the only way to fix is through media query or reducing the content or use the bootstrap mobile menu icon

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top), it says:

> **Body padding required** The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `body`.

Demo: http://bootply.com/133083